# How to solve global equation in Comsol only once?

Tags: comsol

Let's assume that I have a comsol model for solving time-dependent problem. In order to find initial value for one variable I need to solve simple algebraic equation before starting simulation, therefore I added Global ODEs and DAEs module to the model. Now it works good, but it seems like equation from Global ODEs and DAEs module is solved on each time iteration and its obviously redundant calculations, because this equation need to be solved only once.
Questions:

1) Does equation from Global ODEs and DAEs module is solved on each time iterarion or it is only my suggestion? Maybe there is some way how I can check it?

2) If this equation is really solved on each iteration again how can I adjust my solver in order to solve it only once?

Comment: Good question! There is probably too little comsol exptertise around here. You can try to get an answer in the [comsol discussion forum](http://www.comsol.com/community/forums/).